# Modem recycles when power goes out although it's on a UPS

Tags: power, modem, ups

I have a UPS with my desktop, server, router and modem all on the backup side but when the power flickers, the fios modem still powers off.  It is the only thing that powers off.  Anyone know why or how to stop that?

The UPS is new.  I just purchased it 2 months ago.  When the power goes off (the longest its been off since I've had it has been 3 minutes) my server, workstation and router stay on but the modem recycles.  I can't tell if it immediately powers off and then back on or if it power cycles when the power comes back.  Yesterday it was a few outages a few minutes apart but everything except the modem stayed on the whole time.  The Vz modem's light went from green to off then white and back to green.

Comment: No. Please give us more information.

Comment: Probably the UPS battery is weak and is not holding the power, and in the event of a real power outage, it will fail completely.  Some things don't turn off because their internal power conditioning covers the gap.

Comment: @user10489 Great point, however a modem draws only a handful of watts, why wouldn't a server or PC turn off when both use at least 4x the wattage each at the bare minimum and a modem's DC power brick isn't likely to have a bad capacitor _(it's possible, though highly unlikely)_. To determine where the issue lies is relatively easy: swap the modem's DC brick to another backup outlet, then flip the breaker for the UPS outlet; swap out the DC power brick with one of the same voltage and minimum amperage then flip the breaker; pull the UPS metrics via `upsmon` to determine the health of the UPS.

Comment: I think rhe answer here explains the power supply well, but not the UPS.  I bet if you unplug the ups, everything loses power within 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Not everything has the same quality of PSU or is as tolerant of the slight dips that will occur when a UPS switches over from mains to battery.

Unless you have an "online" UPS which is always working to convert down to battery voltage and back up to the output then there is always going to be a changeover time.

Most modern PCs have 115v to 230v tolerant supplies and may also have significant capacitance to account for glitches in the incoming supply and as a result may be able to cope with a momentary interruption during the handful of milliseconds it takes your UPS to detect that the incoming supply has been interrupted and bring its own supply online. Switch mode supplies tend to be highly tolerant of incoming dips and many are capable of working as long as the input voltage does not dip below the required output voltage.

Your router on the other hand might have a cheap power supply that uses a transformer to bring the voltage down to something close to the required voltage but does not take account of incoming voltage dips. As a result the incoming dip causes the output voltage to also dip and as a result browns out the connected device, effectively turning it off.